# How to compile HSL for IPOPT (after IPOPT)

Tags: mingw-w64, hsl, ipopt

I use MINGW64 to compile HSL (https://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/ipopt/) following the redme. However, I end up with an error 2 (Makefile:753). The critical command is

```
gfortran -shared .libs/libcoinhsl-0.dll.def  common/.libs/deps90.o common/.libs/deps.o common/.libs/dump.o mc19/.libs/mc19d.o ma27/.libs/ma27d.o ma28/.libs/ma28d.o ma57/.libs/ma57d.o hsl_ma77/.libs/hsl_ma77d.o hsl_ma77/C/.libs/hsl_ma77d_ciface.o hsl_ma86/.libs/hsl_ma86d.o hsl_ma86/C/.libs/hsl_ma86d_ciface.o hsl_mc68/C/.libs/hsl_mc68i_ciface.o hsl_ma97/.libs/hsl_ma97d.o hsl_ma97/C/.libs/hsl_ma97d_ciface.o loadmetis/.libs/loadmetis.o   -L/mingw64/lib/ -lopenblas -lpthread -lgfortran  -O2 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/mingw64/lib   -o .libs/libcoinhsl-0.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libcoinhsl.dll.a
```

The output is

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: common/.libs/deps90.o:C:\msys64\home\user\hsl_solo\coinhsl/common/deps90.f90:17672: undefined reference to `metis_nodend_'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: common/.libs/deps90.o: in function `__hsl_mc68_integer_MOD_mc68_order_integer':
C:\msys64\home\user\hsl_solo\coinhsl/common/deps90.f90:17454: undefined reference to `metis_nodend_'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ma57/.libs/ma57d.o: in function `ma57ad_':
C:\msys64\home\user\hsl_solo\coinhsl/ma57/ma57d.f:469: undefined reference to `metis_nodend_'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\home\user\hsl_solo\coinhsl/ma57/ma57d.f:682: undefined reference to `metis_nodend_'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\home\user\hsl_solo\coinhsl/ma57/ma57d.f:618: undefined reference to `metis_nodend_'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I am not that experienced with compiling software, does anyone have an idea how I can get this error fixed?

Comment: Also posted at https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL/issues/9.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `metis_nodend_` belongs to Metis.
The `metis_nodend_` symbol needs to be resolved either by linking against a Metis library (you might need to specify where to find that via some flags for configure), by a function of that name that loads the Metis library at runtime (that is what loadmetis tries to do), or by a dummy function of that name that does nothing (thats what older versions of HSL used to do).

The loadmetis of HSL is implemented in C and defines a function `METIS_NODEND`:

```c
void METIS_NODEND(int *nvtxs, int *xadj, int *adjncy, int *numflag,
      int *options, int *perm, int *iperm) {
....
```

So the problem is probably that the naming conventions do not match, i.e., the functionname in the C object does not match the functionname that the Fortran objects expect.

Try changing `METIS_NODEND` to `metis_nodend` or `metis_nodend_` in loadmetis.c.

Or try the buildsystem from https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL/